# "Could not be Bound" SQL error from inner and full join within Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC)

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm relatively new to SQL and am having trouble with some syntax in which I'm attempting both an inner join and full join within the same query.

The first goal of my query is to select a certain set of subscribers via an inner join, and that is working as expected on its own.

From there, I'm trying to use a third table that contains all account IDs (d.NARCID) associated with a Loyalty Program and have it eventually return a TRUE value for any subscribers associated with a Loyalty Program account (LE_Member). I'm trying to use a CASE and FULL JOIN statement to accomplish this.

I cannot get this second portion to work without returning a "The multi-part identifier could not be bound." error.

Below is a sample of the query I'm using. I've removed some fields for readability.

```
SELECT
a.ContactKey,
a.AccountId,
a.NARCID,
a.ParentNARCID,
a.Email,
CASE
WHEN d.NARCID IS NOT NULL THEN 'True'
Else 'False'
END AS LE_Member
FROM
(SELECT 
b.ContactKey,
b.AccountId,
b.ParentNARCID,
b.NARCID,
b.Email,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.Email ORDER BY b.LastModifiedDate DESC) ranking
FROM B2B_US_Master_Journey b 

Inner Join [Beef_All-Accounts_2022] c
On b.NARCID = c.US_NARC_ID__c
Full Join [Beef_LE-Contacts_2022] d
On b.NARCID = d.NARCID
) a
 
WHERE a.ranking = 1
```

Comment: The case expression won't work because it doesn't know `d.narcid` since you're selecting from `A`. I would say either move your join to D on A, or re-write the inner query. Tough to know without having sample data and desired output.

Comment: Amazing, moving the join worked. Thank you so much. I had been updating based on a previous query, and since I'm new to this, I had blinders on about where I should be placing stuff. Thank you again!